# Visual Studio loading wrong view

Tags: html, razor, visual-studio-2013, browser-cache, web-frontend

I am new to Front end development and facing a very weird kind of issue.

I was working on the styling(CSS) of one of Views (let say View A) os MVC application.
**I opened chrome clicked F12 did some changes and clicked ctrl+s.**

Now whatever view I am trying to go I am seeing only static View A. Even if try to go to View A with different url parameters I am seeing old view.

When I tried to browse with IE and tried to debug i see that that at the end of debugging (after going to Controller, Layout, respective View) it loads **blank[dynamic]** page which has html components of View A always.

[image]

**I tried Chrome and IE and I tried Clearing Browser cache, delete browing History etc etc.**

Even If i open any View in **Page Inspector** (of Visual Studio) I see the same behaviour (It is always loading old View A).

When I run my application and see the Output window of visual studio I see it loads **'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet Explorer)'.** 
I deleted the scripts from my application and pasted from a different source but issue remains.

I guess somewhere **in the script this view is saved** and it is loading always this view.

Behavior is same for IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** Finally i saw where is the error.

While editing CSS and saving on Chrome, it saved the View on my layout page.

I removed the content from layout page and it works fine..